# Unit testing using ASP.NET Identity

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-identity

I was wondering how would I go on about unit testing code that use IdentityUser without having to use UserManager (which needs to create a database, etc.). I am also using a Repository pattern with Unit of Work if that makes any difference..

If someone could provide me with more details and a simple example I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So if what you want is just some way to create and store IdentityUsers for unit tests, what you can do is create a TestUserStore and use the UserManager against that store.

```
public class MemoryUser : IUser {
    private readonly IList<UserLoginInfo> _logins;
    private readonly IList<Claim> _claims;
    private readonly IList<string> _roles;

    public MemoryUser(string name) {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        _logins = new List<UserLoginInfo>();
        _claims = new List<Claim>();
        _roles = new List<string>();
        UserName = name;
    }

    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The salted/hashed form of the user password
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// A random value that should change whenever a users credentials have changed (password changed, login removed)
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string SecurityStamp { get; set; }

    public IList<UserLoginInfo> Logins { get { return _logins; } }

    public IList<Claim> Claims { get { return _claims; } }

    public IList<string> Roles { get { return _roles; } }
}

public class MemoryUserStore : IUserStore<MemoryUser>, IUserLoginStore<MemoryUser>, IUserRoleStore<MemoryUser>, IUserClaimStore<MemoryUser>, IUserPasswordStore<MemoryUser>, IUserSecurityStampStore<MemoryUser> {
    private Dictionary<string, MemoryUser> _users = new Dictionary<string, MemoryUser>();
    private Dictionary<UserLoginInfo, MemoryUser> _logins = new Dictionary<UserLoginInfo, MemoryUser>(new LoginComparer());

    public Task CreateAsync(MemoryUser user) {
        _users[user.Id] = user;
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task UpdateAsync(MemoryUser user) {
        _users[user.Id] = user;
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task<MemoryUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId) {
        if (_users.ContainsKey(userId)) {
            return Task.FromResult(_users[userId]);
        }
        return Task.FromResult<MemoryUser>(null);
    }

    public void Dispose() {
    }

    public IQueryable<MemoryUser> Users {
        get {
            return _users.Values.AsQueryable();
        }
    }

    public Task<MemoryUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName) {
        return Task.FromResult(Users.Where(u => u.UserName.ToUpper() == userName.ToUpper()).FirstOrDefault());
    }

    public Task AddLoginAsync(MemoryUser user, UserLoginInfo login) {
        user.Logins.Add(login);
        _logins[login] = user;
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task RemoveLoginAsync(MemoryUser user, UserLoginInfo login) {
        var logs = user.Logins.Where(l => l.ProviderKey == login.ProviderKey && l.LoginProvider == login.LoginProvider).ToList();
        foreach (var l in logs) {
            user.Logins.Remove(l);
            _logins[l] = null;
        }
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task<IList<UserLoginInfo>> GetLoginsAsync(MemoryUser user) {
        return Task.FromResult(user.Logins);
    }

    public Task<MemoryUser> FindAsync(UserLoginInfo login) {
        if (_logins.ContainsKey(login)) {
            return Task.FromResult(_logins[login]);
        }
        return Task.FromResult<MemoryUser>(null);
    }

    public Task AddToRoleAsync(MemoryUser user, string role) {
        user.Roles.Add(role);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task RemoveFromRoleAsync(MemoryUser user, string role) {
        user.Roles.Remove(role);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(MemoryUser user) {
        return Task.FromResult(user.Roles);
    }

    public Task<bool> IsInRoleAsync(MemoryUser user, string role) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<IList<Claim>> GetClaimsAsync(MemoryUser user) {
        return Task.FromResult(user.Claims);
    }

    public Task AddClaimAsync(MemoryUser user, Claim claim) {
        user.Claims.Add(claim);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task RemoveClaimAsync(MemoryUser user, Claim claim) {
        user.Claims.Remove(claim);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task SetPasswordHashAsync(MemoryUser user, string passwordHash) {
        user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(MemoryUser user) {
        return Task.FromResult(user.PasswordHash);
    }

    public Task SetSecurityStampAsync(MemoryUser user, string stamp) {
        user.SecurityStamp = stamp;
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task<string> GetSecurityStampAsync(MemoryUser user) {
        return Task.FromResult(user.SecurityStamp);
    }

    public Task DeleteAsync(MemoryUser user) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<bool> HasPasswordAsync(MemoryUser user) {
        return Task.FromResult(user.PasswordHash != null);
    }
}

var manager = new UserManager<MemoryUser>(new MemoryUserStore())
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! I am getting the following when trying to compile:
Error 6 'WebApp.Tests.UnitTest1.MemoryUserStore' does not implement interface member 'System.IDisposable.Dispose()' D:\WebApp\WebApp\WebApp.Tests\UnitTest1.cs 23 22 WebApp.Tests
Error 7 'WebApp.Tests.UnitTest1.MemoryUserStore' does not implement interface member 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser>.FindByNameAsync(string)' D:\WebApp\WebApp\WebApp.Tests\UnitTest1.cs 23 22 WebApp.Tests

Comment: You have to implement MemoryStore yourself.

Comment: @Hao Kung - could you please provide some more details on how to implement this (ie. what is between the {...} and how would I implement this in a Test)?  For example, I'm trying to test a slightly modified "Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)" in the AccountController and, as a relatively inexperienced MVC developer, I can't get it to work.  Is there any documentation on how to specifically implement your suggestion using something like NSubstitute or Moq?  Thanks!

Comment: I fleshed out the interface implementations, you just need to inject the UserManager<MemoryUser> into the AccountController for your test before calling Register.

Comment: Any thoughts on this? cannot convert from 'X.WebSite.MemoryUserStore' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser>'

Comment: Where does the `LoginComparer` come from? Is that something you implemented yourself? It doesn't seem to be in any of the Identity namespaces.

Comment: How can this be the accepted answer? This code does not work. `UserManager<IdentityUser>` expects a parameter of type `UserStore<IdentityUser>` and `MemoryUser` does not inherit from `IdentityUser`

Comment: @levelnis Actually UserManager only needs something implementing `IUser`. The out-of-box `UserStore` depends on `IdentityUser`. You need your own Userstore if you want to change that, which is exactly what this answer says.

Comment: @shoe but the problem with this code is the initialisation of the `UserManager`. I think simply changing it to this: `var manager = new UserManager<MemoryUser>(new MemoryUserStore())` will solve the problem

Comment: @levelnis Yeah there is a small typo in that line. The approach is correct, however.